# Html(jquery) drag and drop not working in AndroidEmulator

Tags: android, html, jquery

I am new one Android..i created one project in Html...it is running perfectly what i want..i want to run this html project in android emulator..i dont know what is the reason..... Design is came in Android emulator....but drag and drop is only not working in android Emulator.. i have used phonegap to run the html code..if u know pls tel me..Thanks in advance..
This is my Html(jquery code)

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title> - jsFiddle demo by scaillerie</title>
      <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js'></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css">


      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/jquery-ui.js"></script>


      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

      <style type='text/css'>
        .ui-layout-center {
        width: 400px;
        height: 300px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    .ui-state-hover {
        background-color: #f9ffff;   
    }

      </style>



    <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
    $(window).load(function(){
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery(".component").draggable({
            //  use a helper-clone that is append to 'body' so is not 'contained' by a pane
            helper: function() {
                return jQuery(this).clone().appendTo('body').css({
                    'zIndex': 5
                });
            },
            cursor: 'move',
            containment: "document"
        });

        jQuery('.ui-layout-center').droppable({
            activeClass: 'ui-state-hover',
            accept: '.component',
            drop: function(event, ui) {
                if (!ui.draggable.hasClass("dropped"))
                    jQuery(this).append(jQuery(ui.draggable).clone().addClass("dropped").draggable());
                }
            });
        });
    });//]]>  

    </script>


    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="component">Element 1</div>
    <div class="component">Element 2</div>

    <div class="ui-layout-center"> </div>


    </body>


    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, jQuery UI doesn't work properly with touch events. There are, however, a number of plugins to enable touch in jQuery UI, Touch Punch is one: http://touchpunch.furf.com/

You should also consider updating the version of jQuery you're using...v1.4.4 is 3 years old now.

Comment: i cant understand...in that link 4 scripts available... where we place that code?..pls tell clearly....i placed in <head> tag but it is force closed...

Comment: what are the plugings available for jquery?? plz tell me @Adrien Delessert